# Is my understanding of spark partitioning correct?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, partitioning

I'd like to know If my understanding of the partitioning in Spark is correct.
I always thought about *the number of partitions and their size* and never about *the worker they were processed by*.

Yesterday, as I was playing a bit with partitioning, I found out that I was able to track the cached partitions' location using the WEB UI (Storage -> Cached RDD -> Data Distribution) and it surprised me.

I have a cluster of 30 cores (3 cores * 10 executors) and I had a RDD of like 10 partitions. I tried to expand it to 100 partitions to increase the parallelism just to find out that almost 90% of the partitions were on the same worker node and thus my parallelism was not limited by the total number of cpu in my cluster but by the number of cpu of the node containing 90% of the partitions.

I tried to find answers on stackoverflow and the only answer I could come by was about data locality. Spark detected that most of my files were on this node so it decided to keep most of the partitions on this node.

Is my understanding correct?

And if it is, is there a way to tell Spark to **really** shuffle the data?
So far this "data locality" lead to heavy underutilization of my cluster....